Hardhat create account with eth has mysterious balance increase
I'm new to solidity, testing out smart contracts and I just set up Hardhat.  I created a random account with 10 Eth for testing.  Here is the code for the script:
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  // Create a random wallet
  const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
  console.log("New account address:", wallet.address);
  console.log("Private key:", wallet.privateKey);

  // Get the first signer (default account) from Hardhat
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  // Set the balance of the new account to 10 ETH (10 * 10^18 wei)
  const balance = "0x8ac7230489e80000";
  await network.provider.send("hardhat_setBalance", [
    wallet.address,
    balance,
  ]);

  console.log("Funded new account with 10 ETH");
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

This account was successfully created with 10 eth.  I sent 1 eth as a deposit to the smart contract - this was successful and the balance is 9 eth for the wallet and 1 eth for the contract.  I tried to withdraw, which was unsuccessful due to errors in my smart contract.  I tried to edit it but had problems deploying the new contract.  I am still stuck here at this stage.  A day later I come back and my wallet is back to 10 Eth, and my original, faulty smart contract with the bad withdraw function is still at 1 eth.
No, I did not run the script twice because if I did it would have set up a new account.
Does anybody have any idea what's going on?

